# How does active directory affect client desktop performance

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, windows-domain

I'm trying to understand the scope of Windows Domain/AD login. In particular, I have a client PC which when logged in over a remote connection/offsite, the UI/applications of the desktop becomes very slow(EG, opening Google Chrome can take 10 seconds(to blank page), opening a simply web page, google.com, can also take 10 sec), all while the desktops resource are not burdened, if anything everything looks idle(Task Manager). I've been search for how WD/AD works but have not come up with much in the way of explanation of the inner workings which could explain this issue(possibly partly due to my lack of knowledge of WD/AD). Any explanation or links are greatly welcomed.

Some points to be addressed ideally:

- Does AD have a Remote Desktop style operation?(IE, logging into windows actually means logging into the WDC/AD as a RDP session)
- Do desktop application operations pass through WDC/AD?
- Could Windows OS updates be happening and be completely hidden from user(Task Manger)?

Comment: Windows Update would not appear in Task Manager since Windows Update is handled by a service not a process (although the service might appear there isn’t any indication a update is being downloaded).  Have you tried asking your IT Administrator for assistance?

Answer (score 0):

> Does AD have a Remote Desktop style operation?(IE, logging into windows actually means logging into the WDC/AD as a RDP session)

AD on its own – no. It is a fully local session with only network-based password checks, and *possibly* network-hosted files (e.g. your Desktop or Documents could be hosted on a fileserver, but your apps are entirely local).

However, Windows *does* have Remote Desktop style operation (Hyper-V based Virtual Desktop Infrastructure), although that is a completely separate service. AD is only a starting point for integrating it.

> Do desktop application operations pass through WDC/AD?

No, except those which actually use user account management features (i.e. user authentication, SID-to-username lookup). Most normal programs' operation does not involve AD at all.

> Could Windows OS updates be happening and be completely hidden from user(Task Manger)?

Active Directory does not do that. AD allows you to deploy Group Policy settings, which could disable Task Manager completely, but there is no setting to hide individual processes, or to pretend that Windows Update isn't running when it actually is.

(You can run gpedit.msc to see the same policy settings on any Windows Pro system.)